# Add[ing] a splendid production

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, subjects

Which one of these sentences is more grammatically correct?:

> 1. Add a splendid production and you have a certified hit.
> 2. Adding a splendid production and you have a certified hit.

Why, grammatically, is (1) better than (2) or vice versa? And what type of clause is the first clause in the sentence?

Comment: Neither seems to stand on its own. What is the context? E.g. what is the splendid production being added to?

Answer (score 1):

Option (1) is correct here. Because the sentence is present tense, not past or future tense.

The second sentence would have to read;

> “Adding a splendid production WILL give you a certified hit.”

The word “adding” is a verb and in this context it is about a future action.

The first sentence, is a command or suggestion; “ADD sugar to make your cookies sweet.” Vs. “Adding sugar WILL make your cookies sweet.”

Comment: It's nothing to do with tense. In the first one, _and_ is coordinating two sentences, which is fine (even if the first sentence is formally an imperative). In the second, _and_ is coordinating an _-ing_ clause (which in most ways acts like a noun phrase) and a sentence: that is incoherent.